# Finding ordered pairs for trigonometric Equation in two variables

Tags: trigonometry

If $0\le x,y \le3\pi$ and $cosx.siny =1$ Then the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ is:

(A)4 
(B)8 
(C)6
(D)12 .

I actually plotted and solved this but is it solvable otherwise(by patterns(periodicity) or other trig concepts) ?

Thanks.

Comment: __Hint:__ $|\cos x| \leq 1$ and $|\sin y| \leq 1$. When can their product be 1?

Comment: @CalvinLin  Got that ! Thanks..

Comment: In that case, can you write up your solution below so that others can learn from it?

Comment: Sure. I'll do that..

Answer (score 1):

So, as Calvin Lin wrote in the comments we know  that$ -1\le$$ \cos x$ and $\sin y $$\le1.$ So their product can be $1$ only if both are $1$ or$-1$ 
Now in $(0,3\pi)$ we get six such ordered pairs(Notice form graphs of sine and cosine) .